# Odata T4 Item Template not working in iOS device with special linker behaviour in MvvmCross

Tags: ios, xamarin

When I generate Odata proxy code and run on iOS device, it doesn't get any data from server with "Link framework sdks only".
I face these problems so frequently, wonder now these are Xamarin issues or did I not know something special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Xamarin error. You can downgrade Xamarin version and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but can you tell me the version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used t4 template class to get odata data from server.
but I used simple odata client component for Odata apis, and it works fine with all linker behaviors.
Please try this and will help you.